# creating identical svg elements with Qt and read it back with different id sets

Tags: c++, xml, qt, svg

I'm working on svg creating and loading in a project with Qt, the problem is where I want to create different elements with different elementIds and also load them back from file and identify them by their ids, a list of element ids also would be nice.

I've read Qt::Svg package documentation and tried to save and load svg files, also read the codes of Qt::Svg and found out behind the API of qtsvg it's a list of elements with their element id's but it's not ported to the API here:
https://github.com/qt/qtsvg/blob/347de1dd25366015e3fbbc39ccd1a16ecb18eb2e/src/svg/qsvgtinydocument_p.h#L131

I use the typical documented Qt procedure to save and load svg from/to QGraphicsScene with QSvgGenerator and QSvgRenderer

```cpp
void MainWindow::saveClicked()
{
    QString fileName = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this,
          tr("Save as SVG"), QString(), tr("SVG Files (*.svg)"));

    QSvgGenerator generator;
    generator.setFileName(fileName);
    generator.setSize(QSize(1000, 1000));
    generator.setViewBox(QRect(0, 0, 1000, 1000));
    generator.setTitle(tr("SVG Generator Example Drawing"));
    generator.setDescription(tr("An SVG drawing created by the SVG Generator "));

    QPainter painter;
    painter.begin(&generator);
    scene->render(&painter);
    painter.end();
}
```

```cpp
void MainWindow::on_loadBtn_clicked()
{
    QString svgPath = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Choose svg file"), QString(),
                                                   "SVGs (*.svg)");

    QFile svgFile(svgPath);
    if (!svgFile.exists())
        return;

    QSvgRenderer renderer(svgPath);

    QGraphicsSvgItem *svgItem = new QGraphicsSvgItem(svgPath);
//    svgItem->setElementId("rect10");
    if (!svgItem->renderer()->isValid())
        return;

    svgItem->setFlags(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable | QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable);
    scene->addItem(svgItem);
}
```

the result is this(for example a simple circle):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg width="352.778mm" height="352.778mm"
 viewBox="0 0 1000 1000"
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  version="1.2" baseProfile="tiny">
<title>SVG Generator Example Drawing</title>
<desc>An SVG drawing created by the SVG Generator </desc>
<defs>
</defs>
<g fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-linejoin="bevel" >

<g fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-linejoin="bevel" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)"
font-family="MS Shell Dlg 2" font-size="8.25" font-weight="400" font-style="normal" 
>
</g>

<g fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-linejoin="bevel" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,422,602)"
font-family="MS Shell Dlg 2" font-size="8.25" font-weight="400" font-style="normal" 
>
<circle cx="37.5" cy="37.5" r="37.5"/>
</g>

<g fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-linejoin="bevel" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,422,602)"
font-family="MS Shell Dlg 2" font-size="8.25" font-weight="400" font-style="normal" 
>
</g>

<g fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-linejoin="bevel" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)"
font-family="MS Shell Dlg 2" font-size="8.25" font-weight="400" font-style="normal" 
>
</g>
</g>
</svg>
```

I wanted to know if there is no other alternative provided by Qt::Svg library or is there any third-party open source software that provide a better svg manipulation API in Qt?
or can you suggest a solution? xml-manipulation? subclass QSvgGenerator and QSvgRenderer? or Idk :))

the problem is that I can call to load just one element Id but how can I know the element Ids list to load them separately...

Comment: As far as I understood the doc.: A `QSvgRenderer` can convert/compile a sequence of paint primitives (applied to a `QPainter`) into an SVG file. It surely must have an internal representation of it. (Otherwise, `load()` wouldn't make sense.) `QGraphicsSvgItem` is a `QGraphicsItem` to embed a `QSvgRenderer` (with some contents) into a `QGraphicsScene`. May be, you might have expected that `QSvgRenderer` uses internally `QGraphicsItem`s as well. This doesn't seem the case (or the graphics items are not exposed in API). `QSvgRenderer` is probably not the right tool for what you intend.

Comment: [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/) is an open source development of vector graphics paint tool. It supports SVG (if not built up on). It's developed in C++ and gtkmm. (To bad for you). However, the scene graph part might be good for your inspiration if you think about to setup your own SVG editor (e.g. based on `QGraphicsItem`s etc.) And, btw. the [sources of `QSvg`](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtsvg/src/svg/) might be an inspiration as well, of course.

Comment: thank you for your commend and guidance, I will look into Inkscape codes maybe try a little to understand gtkmm to figure out how it manages the element names and ids and I will try to extend the ability of QtSvg by the way I doubt that there would be no other alternative open source solution provided by anyone else.